# unable to add user to group fedora 29

Tags: fedora, usermod

I  used groupadd to add a group so that I could manage with git some root owned scripts.
I then used usermod to add a user to a group.  The user is the currently logged in standard user and I am in a shell through su into the superuser account in the terminal.  I logged out and logged back in again, having run

```
sudo usermod -aGgroupname username
```

as I always have done.  After I logged back in as the standard user, the  command groups continued to show just the user, but when I logged in to the superuser account and ran

```
groups stdusername
```

the output showed that the std user is a member of the new group.
I don't understand how this can happen.

Comment: I've just run 'groups username' from the std user account and it shows the added group.  So why does the command 'groups' only show the user's own group?

Comment: Does `groups` show *any* supplementary groups? if not, check if a buggy kwallet pam module is involved - see [Lost supplementary user groups for GUI login session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059856/lost-supplementary-user-groups-for-gui-login-session/1059997#1059997)

Comment: have you tried  `newgrp groupname`  as this user?

Comment: Same problem here:
///
cat /etc/group => docker:x:975:romeokienzler
///
groups romeokienzler => romeokienzler : romeokienzler wheel libvirt docker
///
id => uid=1000(romeokienzler) gid=1000(romeokienzler) groups=1000(romeokienzler),10(wheel),984(libvirt) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
///
ls -lahr /var/run/docker.sock  => srw-rw----. 1 root docker 0 Sep  6 09:12 /var/run/docker.sock
///
docker ps
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/cont...

Answer (score 0):

Did you reboot / re-login?

> sudo pkill -SIGKILL -u ${USER}

did the job for me as desrcibed [here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/why-dont-supplemental-groups-take-effect-without-a-reboot/11252)

Seems to be a feature of Fedora - not happening on Ubuntu